# Java Morsecode Translator

Tags: java, morse-code

i've got a problem with my Java Morsecode Translator. 
I made two arrays filled with the Characters and the MorseCode. If I want to translate Morsecode to text the method decode()

```
public String decode(String mc) {
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    // trim() removes whitespaces before or after String
    String mctrim = mc.trim();
    //Morsecode has a short Pause (1 Whitespace) between every character 
    //and a long Pause (3 Whitespaces) between words
    //Splitting the Morsecode to get chars 
    if (mctrim.contains(kurzePause)) {
        String[] mcsplit2 = mctrim.split(kurzePause);
        for (int i = 0; i < mcsplit2.length; i++) {
            sb2.append(getCharacter(mcsplit2[i]));
        }
    }
    return sb2.toString();
```

should get every character through the method getCharacter().
If the character is not listed in the array a '$' is displayed in the sentence. Now i've declared kurzePause (short Pause) and langePause (long Pause) as variables. A whitespace is not part of my array.

How can I split the String that makes a distinction between a block of three whitespaces (longPause) and only one whitespace (shortPause)

An example for a given output for a correct Morsecode (`.--- .- ...- .-   -- .- -.-. .... -   ... .--. .- ... ... .-.-.-`):
`JAVA$$MACHT$$SPASS`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could split into sentences first (long pause) and during the iteration you can split the current sentence into words (short pause).

Comment: If I understand it well, the `mc` parameter is your Morse code, that is a string containing only `.`, `-` and spaces ? And `getCharacter` actually returns the letter corresponding to a given sequence of `.` and `-` ?

Answer (score 0):

Java regular expressions allow to specify the number of occurrences. `mctrim.split("\\s{3,}"`) should split the string into sentences (3 or more spaces), then you can further split sentences using trivial `"\\s+"`.